# How to implement periodic cache reload

Tags: c#

```
public class Cache<TKey, TValue> : ICache<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _internalCache;
    private readonly object _syncLock = new object();

    public Cache()
    {
        _internalCache = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_syncLock) {
               //...
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_syncLock) {
               //...
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> GetAll()
    {
        lock (_syncLock) {
            return _internalCache.Values;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            return _internalCache.ContainsKey(key);
        }
    }

}
```

The above cache is used by a singleton wrapper. The following is the implementation.

```
public class ActivityCache : ICache<string, Activity> 
 {
    private readonly ICache<string, Activity> _cache = new Cache<string, Activity>();

    private static readonly ActivityCache _instance = new ActivityCache();

    // http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html
    static ActivityCache()
    {
    }

    ActivityCache()
    {
    }

    public static ActivityCache Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public Activity this[string activityUrl]
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activityUrl))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return _cache[activityUrl];
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activityUrl))
            {
                return;
            }

            _cache[activityUrl] = value;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Activity> GetAll()
    {
        return _cache.GetAll();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _cache.ContainsKey(key);
    }
}
```

Now my question is if I want to reload cache, can i use the following? I want to make the reload seamless, so that its OK to have threads access stale information.

```
public void Reload(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> values)
{
    cache = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> value in values)
    {
        cache[value.Key] = value.Value;
    }

    lock (_syncLock)
    {
        _internalCache = cache;
    }
}
```

_internalCache is readonly. It won't let me change assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The `_internalCache` is read only (and I assume you don't just want to remove the `readonly` keyword to make things work). But that  only affects the reference to the list. You can still replace the items *within* the list, like this:

```
public void Reload(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> values)
{
    lock(_synclock)
    {
        _internalCache.Clear();
        _internalCache.AddRange(values);
    }
}
```

Also, instead of writing all those locks yourself, perhaps you could consider using a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides methods for accessing keys in a safe fashion, and even allows you to supply a delegate for repopulating an entry if a key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Accctualy, you do not need to recreate the dictionary (given it is readonly). You could clear all values, just calling `Clear()` method from `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. For sample:

```
public void Reload(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> values)
{
    lock (_synclock)
    {
       _internalCache.Clear();

       foreach (var value in values)
          _internalCache.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think you need a `lock` in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it could be better. Thank you @JohnWu

Comment: thanks, but i want to dispose off old cache only after creating new one to have a seamless change in state.

Comment: by clearing the cache before populating, its possible that foreground threads have a cache miss. I am ok serving stale data. So i was trying this approach.